# Efficient Conversion of a Large Integer List to Boolean List

Tags: list-manipulation

I am working on a problem where I need to generate a list of random Boolean values. My current approach is to first generate a list of random integers (0 or 1), and then convert this list to a Boolean list. However, I am struggling to find an efficient way to perform this conversion.

My current method uses the `Map` function, but it's quite slow, especially when dealing with large lists. Here's my code:

```mathematica
Module[{v = RandomInteger[{0, 1}, 10000000]}, 
 AbsoluteTiming[# != 0 & /@ v]]
```

This operation takes around 1.96 seconds to run on my machine, which is too slow for my needs.

I am looking for a more efficient way to convert a large list of integers to a Boolean list. Any suggestions or improvements would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `AbsoluteTiming[v = RandomChoice[{False, True}, 10000000]]`

Comment: @Syed Thank you! It's indeed much faster, takes 0.165785 seconds, while I find RandomInteger is even faster, takes 0.0229642 seconds.

Comment: I left it as a comment as your first sentence says: `I need to generate a list of random Boolean values` and it changes to `I am looking for a more efficient way to convert a large list of integers to a Boolean list` at the end.

Comment: If you are working with massive numbers of Booleans, maybe it'd be faster to *change* your code to take `{0,1}` instead of `{False,True}` since `AbsoluteTiming[v = RandomInteger[{0, 1}, 10000000];]` is about 2 times faster than `AbsoluteTiming[v = RandomChoice[{True, False}, 10000000];]`

This may be irrelevant to your application though, as the main bottleneck in your code could be somewhere else

Comment: Why can't you generate these random boolean values on the fly?

Comment: `v /. {0 -> False, 1 -> True}` should be faster than your approach, if you must start from numerical values. Direct generation of an array of Boolean values with `RandomChoice` will still be faster though.